# How to remove url prefix and redirect it?

Tags: redirects

I had urls with /content/ prefix e.g. mysite.com/content/bla-bla-bla/
now I whant redirect all to mysite.com/bla-bla-bla/ without /content/
Is this possible?
Thanks!

Comment: Apache? IIS? NGINX? What software? Can you use Rewrites? Need more info

Answer (score 5):

It is possible -- but you need to tell at least which web server do you use.

For Apache this can be achieved with the following rule (using mod_rewrite):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^content/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

If you are using Microsoft IIS7.x then it is also possible with the help of URL Rewrite Module (you may need to download and install it separately -- depends which IIS version you have):

```
<rule name="redirect /content/" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^content/(.+)$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```